# How can googletest preserve the test code during linking?

Tags: c++, linker, googletest

I have a small test project with the following layout:

```
testmain.cc
Foo\
  |--FooClass1_test.cc
  |--FooClass2_test.cc
Bar\
  |--BarClass1_test.cc
  |--BarClass2_test.cc
```

In the *_test files I have defined tests along the lines of

```
TEST(Foo, foo_func1_works)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(42, the_answer);
}
```

And testmain.cc contains only:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I can see that the TEST macros generate self-registering classes which `RUN_ALL_TESTS` will know about, but how is this code linked? Nothing references the tests defined in the .cc files, no includes etc. Why does the linker **not** throw this code away? I am compiling the project with MSVC 2010.

Comment: @close voter please explain why you think the question is not clear.

Comment: Is your question how the linker knows about all those files?  That would seem to be a question specific to your build system and build configuration.

Or is your question why the registration code isn't "pruned" in some way?

Comment: @NicholasM It's the second: "Why does the linker not throw this code away?"